# Stuck in Emergency mode 18.04.5

Tags: 16.04

My Linux system is stuck in emergency mode and is giving me a bunch of errors... I haven‘t found any help online that actually worked for me, maybe some of you know whats going on here. I‘ve included a picture of the screen.
Thanks for the Help!

[image]

Comment: `/dev/disk/by-uuid/F95E-F2DF` is the same type of UUID a USB drive would create.  Are you booting off a USB drive or did you leave one in during your boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Howdie how2die,

Have you recently formstted a disk or partition on your machine? This sort of error will appear when the UUID of a partition specified on `/etc/fstab` cannot be found.

Try this:

```
sudo blkid
```

Record the UUIDs of the different partitions, then

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

Compare the UUIDs of the partitions to the ones you wrote down. If any of them do not match, then update the record. Based on the error you shared, this is probably the EFI partition that has changed, which you’ll see in `/etc/fstab` with `type=efi`.

Hope this helps.